# Connect Operation timed out while running mvn test

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

I have created a new `quarkus` project using [online tool](https://code.quarkus.io/) with `kotlin` extenstion. I am able to execute `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev` and curl on http://localhost:8080. However I am getting following exception while executing `./mvnw test`.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running dev.sanket.ExampleResourceTest
2020-02-20 14:06:27,010 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.2.1.Final started in 0.411s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8081
2020-02-20 14:06:27,013 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated.
2020-02-20 14:06:27,013 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, kotlin, resteasy]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 78.626 s <<< FAILURE! - in dev.sanket.ExampleResourceTest
[ERROR] testHelloEndpoint  Time elapsed: 76.099 s  <<< ERROR!
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Trying out further it looks like, when O specify quarkus.http.host=localhost, the test works. There seems to be some configuration on my machine which prevents the test to connect using 0.0.0.0. I tried curl http://0.0.0.0:8081/greetings and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default [configuration](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config) for `quarkus.http.host` is `0.0.0.0`, if you want to run it as localhost while you are only in test phase, then you can add this to your properties file :

> %test.quarkus.http.host=localhost

It is like specifying a set of properties for certain profile. It can be applied to other properties as well.

Further links : [profiling and configuration in Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/config).

Comment: just had the same issue and it solves it thanks ! 
Almost the same solution, if you don't want to update your application.properties for some reason :  create a ".env" file at project root containing "QUARKUS_HTTP_HOST: localhost"