# Quarkus quickstart example test - Connection refused

Tags: testing, quarkus

Beginning with Quarkus, I build the getting-started-example and it works fine. But if I run the tests with `mvn test` it doesn't work, I'm getting a connection refused error. The port 8081 is ok, so what's wrong with it?

```
[INFO] Running org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResourceTest
2020-02-20 07:55:20,150 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Quarkus 1.1.0.Final started in 0.080s.
2020-02-20 07:55:20,154 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile test activated.
2020-02-20 07:55:20,154 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: []
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.345 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResourceTest
[ERROR] testHelloEndpoint  Time elapsed: 3.192 s  <<< ERROR!
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResourceTest.testHelloEndpoint(GreetingResourceTest.java:17)
[ERROR] testGreetingEndpoint  Time elapsed: 2.029 s  <<< ERROR!
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.acme.quickstart.GreetingResourceTest.testGreetingEndpoint(GreetingResourceTest.java:23)
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to the getting-started code or to `pom.xml`?

Comment: I think you are facing the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312410/connect-operation-timed-out-while-running-mvn-test/60313194#60313194) as this guy faced.

Comment: %test.quarkus.http.host=localhost didn't help. And I didn't change pom.xml. Even on a new PC with Win10 it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Quarkus to 1.2.1.Final solved the problem, tests are working now.